# Project Management Tools Capable of Assisting with Local File Management

Tags: file-management, project-management

**Required Features (in order of importance)**

1) Looking for project management applications that are capable of linking to files stored on a local server. Users would be able to view a project on a calendar, click a link, and be brought to the corresponding project's assets folder on the local server

2) Locally running applications preferred since browser based access to local file storage is generally frowned upon

3) Ubiquitous, well supported systems

4) Doesn’t require overly proprietary customization (such as Salesforce)

5) Spreadsheet based project tracking would be nice since current data needs to be migrated from one

**Use Case**

Many media editors need to access large, locally stored files while tracking the progress of related projects.

**Price Point**

- Unlimited users (preferred)
- Per user pricing would need to be < $50 per user per month

**Operating Systems**

- Windows
- Mac
- Linux (not required, but nice to have)

**Additional Details**

One tool-set I'm already aware of is [Shotgun by Autodesk](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219030938-Linking-to-Local-Files). Trying to find alternatives that are less expensive and more ubiquitous.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy. Let me know if I can provide any further details.

Comment: Should be good now (though I've never heard of an operating system named "PC", but that must not necessarily mean it doesn't exist – or did you mean Windows? Runs on the same PCs that can run Linux :)

Comment: Yeah you know it’s the new politically correct systems. Just kidding, ya got me